# hover event problem with jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

hi all im building a menu and im trying to put an hover effect on each menu item
but... when i hover everything is working great and i get the html i want and the menu item has a backgruond image.

but the unhover effect dosnt fire most of the times. i found out that if i move my mouse horziantly across the ul menu it works fine. but if my mouse does a vertical move across the li item it dosnt fire.
my code is this:

```
 $("ul.menu li").hover(ChangeToHoverMenuItem, ChangeBackMenuItem);
 function ChangeToHoverMenuItem()
 {
    var currLi = $(this);
    lastLi = currLi;
    var currMenuItemText = currLi.find("a").text();
    currLi.html("");

    currLi.append("<div style='float:right;'><div class='right_item_hov'></div>" +
                "<a class='item_menu_hov'>" +
                currMenuItemText +
                "</a>" +
                "<div class='left_item_hov'></div></div>");
 }

 function ChangeBackMenuItem ()
 {
     var currLi = $(this);
     var currMenuItemText = currLi.find("a").text();

     currLi.html("");
     currLi.append("<a>" + currMenuItemText + "</a>");

 }

     <div class="menu_middle">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>
            <a>
                main
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>
                gallery
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>
                event
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>                
            <a>
               about
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>
                contact
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

thank you

Comment: Your code is working for me as expected (on Firefox 3.6.8/Ubuntu). What browser do you use? Did you test it in other browsers?

Comment: no i actualy tried only firefox on windows 7. this can be maybe because weird css i have on this site.. its a rounded corner frame which is half transparent because of rgb. and it has stuff like position relative.. i think this could be the reason why its not working... ill further test it and tell you later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strange thing is, that there are two `mouseenter()` events on sibling elements without a `mouseleave()` event in between.

One idea is to register the `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` event instead of using `hover()`. `hover()` should do the same, but how knows. If this works, the problem lies in the implementation of `hover()` but I don't think so.

```
$("ul.menu li")
  .mouseenter(ChangeToHoverMenuItem)
  .mouseleave(ChangeBackMenuItem);
```

Another idea is to ensure  that the `mouseleave()` code was executed. In your "doHover" handler you can check if there is an`hoveredItem`. If so, you can call the `ChangeBackMenuItem` function with the still hovered item as `this`. To ensure that the "unhover" handler is called when you leave your ul, you need a `mouseleave` event on this, that does the same. This solution relies on a working `mouseleave` on the ul element.

```
$(function() {

 var hoveredItem = null;

 function ChangeToHoverMenuItem()
 {
    if (hoveredItem) {
       ChangeBackMenuItem.call(hoveredItem);
    }
    hoveredItem = this;

    var currLi = $(this);
    lastLi = currLi;
    var currMenuItemText = currLi.find("a").text();
    currLi.html("");

    currLi.append("" +
                "" +
                currMenuItemText +
                "" +
                "");
 }

 function ChangeBackMenuItem ()
 {
     var currLi = $(this);
     var currMenuItemText = currLi.find("a").text();

     currLi.html("");
     currLi.append("" + currMenuItemText + "");
     hoveredItem = null;

 }

 $("ul.menu li").hover(ChangeToHoverMenuItem, ChangeBackMenuItem);
 $("ul.menu").mouseleave(function() {
   if (hoveredItem) {
     ChangeBackMenuItem.call(hoveredItem);
     hoveredItem = null;
   }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a boundary to the li (using css 'border' property) and then add a console.log([firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/)) statement in the beginning of 'ChangeBackMenuItem' to see if the function is called each time you un-hover.

Comment: hi tnx for the reply. giving it a border did help. but... it still not perfect. if i move fast with my mouse the unhover event dosnt get fired. so im stuck with the html from my hover event. and also i cant give it a border because its not a solid color at the background. its a gradiant. and when i tried a transparent background it looks wierd.